# Как правильно писать слово "Бог"?

Tags: орфография, ономастика

С большой или с маленькой буквы пишется слово "Бог"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "Бог" пишется с большой буквы, если речь идет о Всевышнем, Боге в понимании христианской и мусульманской доктрины. Также с большой буквы пишутся все синонимы (Всевышний, Господь и т.д.) и местоимения обозначающие Его.
Пример: *"Говоря о Боге, мы не можем не вспомнить о Его милости..."*
Когда речь идет о языческих божествах, либо же слово употребляется в переносном смысле, тогда оно пишется с маленькой буквы.
Пример: *"Он сам себе и царь, и бог".*

Answer (score 0):

Если свой — то Бог, а если чужой — то бог.

> Каценеленбоген добродушно кивнул: ― Да, я верю в **Бога**.[Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]
>
> И хоть я никогда не верила, да и сейчас не верю в **бога**, но в тот день, когда Костя вернулся, подумала: слава тебе, Господи! [Эдуард Русаков. Как я умирала // «Сибирские огни», 2013]
>
> Рабочее государство теперь хочет изгнать из себя эту фальшивую религию: молись своему **богу**, как хочешь, но молчи про него и не навязывай его другому: для твоего соседа по рабочему станку это совсем неинтересно. [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1924)]
>
> Молись своему **богу**, а я своему, ― молитва точит и тупит меч, наносит и отводит Удары. [А. Ф. Вельтман. Светославич, вражий питомец Диво времен Красного Солнца Владимира (1837)]

Comment: А вот в таком предложении: "Хоть я и христианин, но знаю, что в исламе Аллах — это Бог, творец всего сущего". По Вашему правилу выходит, что я написал с ошибкой? Это простой пример, а вообще я не согласен с Вашим категоричным ответом.

Comment: @grizzly В моем ответе я предложил некий подход к проблеме, а в деталях все сложнее, конечно. В Вашем примере христианин говорит о Боге, творце всего сущего — такой Бог существует с точки зрения христианина тоже, поэтому с прописной.

Answer (score -1):

Слово "бог" (и другие слова, в том числе слово "вы") пишется с прописной, когда хотите придать некоторое чувственное значение (уважение, признание, особенность, а может быть и насмешку, издевку). Это простое слово, его можно писать и с простой строчной буквы, ничего особенного.