# Как писать слово Б(б)ог?

Tags: орфография

Я - атеист, но оскорблять чьи-либо религиозные чувства желания не испытываю. В связи с этим  возникла пара вопросов:
 1. Как писать слово Б(б)ог, если я имею в виду не одного, а несколько богов монотеистических религий?
 2. Если имею в виду богов и моно-  и политеистических верований?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спор бесконечный. 
Я думаю, что надо все-таки признать различие подходов нормативной и церковной орфографии, хотя за последнее время они отчасти сближаются.

По нынешним нормам Бог пишется с заглавной в случае если имеется в виду собственно Бог в понимании монотеизма или аналогичного подхода в других религиях (буддизма, например). 
Если же имеется в виду "один из многих" богов, то со строчной. Также не используется заглавная в случаях, когда бог используется в переносном смысле и в устойчивых выражениях. Никаких конфессиональных мотивов в таком подходе нет.

Церковный же подход опирается именно на религиозную суть. Единый Бог христиан  (и с оговорками - иудеев и мусульман) заслуживает написания с заглавной, остальные - нет, вне зависимости от положения и роли. При этом по церковным правилам с заглавной пишется и все, что связано с именем Божьим, чего уж никак не может признать "официальная" орфография.

Answer (score 1):

В практике письма последних двух десятилетий преодолено требование «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года писать со строчной буквы многие названия, связанные с религией (такое правило в 1956 году было обусловлено идеологическими причинами). Сейчас слова Бог, Господь, Богородица и т. п. рекомендуется писать с большой буквы. При этом дело не в религиозной позиции пишущего (она может быть любой), а в том, что слова Бог, Господь, Богородица, Аллах и т. п. – индивидуальные названия, являющиеся фактически собственными именами.

Итак, сейчас во всех текстах (религиозных и нерелигиозных) рекомендуется писать: Бог, если имеется в виду единое верховное существо в монотеистических религиях. В формах множественного числа, а также в значении одного из множества богов или в переносном значении слово бог пишется со строчной: боги Олимпа, бог Аполлон, бог войны.

C прописной буквы рекомендуется писать и прилагательные, образованные от слова Бог: Божий, Божественный. В переносном значении употребляется только строчная буква: божественный вкус, бабушка божий одуванчик.

В устойчивых сочетаниях, употребляющихся в разговорной речи вне прямой связи с религией следует писать слово бог (а также господь) только со строчной буквы. Вне зависимости от религиозной позиции пишущего ошибкой будет написание ей-Богу. Также невозможна прописная буква в таком контексте: у него все не слава богу.

Если Вам ответ показался не полным, поищите в "Справке" на портале "Грамота.ру".

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что у атеиста любой Б(б)ог является одним из множества. У Бога христиан и евреев к тому же есть конкретные имена (Саваоф, ЙХВХ), что запутывает ещё больше. Если я под богом имею в виду Кришну или Аллаха мне писать с большой или малой? А если Ахуру-Мазду? Одним из множества он не является, так как единственный властитель света, но властителем тьмы является Ариман.  
В любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, слово "Бог", так же как "Он","Его", пишется с прописной буквы в церковной литературе. Правилами правописание предусмотрена строчная буква в слове "бог"

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3&stype=0 тут можно просмотреть различные толкования слова "Б(б)ог и во многих случаях указывают, на правильность написания именно с заглавной буквы в ряде вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

[Повтор вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/69/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3)
А вообще, слово Бог пишется исключительно с большой буквы, если речь идет о Боге, а не о языческих божествах. В любой литературе.

Comment: Попрошу всё же снова открыть вопрос, так как повтора в данном случае нет. По приведённой вами ссылке спрашивается о написании слова бог, о чём можно узнать в любом орфографическом или толковом словаре. Меня же интересуют примеры написания данного слова, которые словари не рассматривают, о чем и написано в дополнении к вопросу.  
С вашим объяснением, тоже не всё понятно. Чем Бог отличается от неБога? и с какой буквы мне грамотно писать данное слово, если я имею в виду одновременно Аллаха, Иегову, ЙХВХ, Кришну и прочих монотеистических богов?